# Django: creating a form from different models

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating the *"Order"* form for the Parts.

My `AddOrderForm` has `Order` Model fields (like `quantity`) but at the same time some Part-related info from `Part` Model (like `name_in_english`) and `PartNumber` Model (like `number`) and some other fields...

**First** I did Separate `ModelForm` for each one and them combined them like this:

## forms.py

```
class PartNumberForAddOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PartNumber
        fields = ('number',)

class PartForAddOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ('manufacturer','name_in_english')

class AddOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('quantity',)
```

in template:

```
<form class="form-inline well" id="add_order">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">

        {% crispy form_part_number %}
        {% crispy form_part %}
        {% crispy form_order %}
        
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="{% trans 'Add' %}"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

With this view became:
`form_part_number.is_valid() and form_part.is_valid() and form_order.is_valid():`

All this looks SUPER ugly and just wrong...

So I created the other way:

```
class PartForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ('manufacturer','name_in_english')

class PartNumberForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PartNumber
        fields = ('number',)

class AddOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manufacturer = PartForm.base_fields['manufacturer']
    name_in_english = PartForm.base_fields['name_in_english']
    number = PartNumber.base_fields['number']

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('manufacturer','number','quantity','name_in_english')
```

QUESTIONS: Is this `Form.base_fields['']` legal way? I assume the `.save()` will not work, but `.is_valid()` should be fine, right? Is there any better way to do it?

I could fine anything helpful anywhere so this is something I came up with myself. and that worries me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is_valid()` call will probably validate the individual fields correctly, but it might ignore other model validation, for example a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) statement or a custom [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method on one of the other models.

I don't think that checking `is_valid()` for multiple forms is that ugly. I've used it before, and immediately understand what you're doing. However, I've never seen anyone define a form by grabbing a fields from another forms `base_fields` before. That doesn't mean it won't work, but it is unconventional.

If you're really concerned about it being ugly, you could do something like the following:

```
my_forms = [form_part_number, form_part, form_order]
if all(f.is_valid() for f in my_forms):
    ...
```

Comment: @Alasdair, in my actual case I had to use 5 "forms" in one form - 2 of them due to the order of the fields that I wanted. But what makes me sick to my stomach is the fact that I'm using multiple "forms" in one actual form. I'm new to Django and trying to figure things out.

Comment: I'm still sticking to `base_fields`... so far so good. Thank you, Alasdair